# Как сделать чекбокс с выбором всех чекбоксов в TableView на JavaFX и FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно при клике чекбокса, который сверху, переключать флажки в поле у всего списка в таблице. А потом при клике на кнопку удалить выбранные записи, удалять выбранные записи из базы данны MySQL.

Вот что удалось наковырять:

**PersonUnpersonValueFactoryController.java**

```
package usersapp.controller;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import usersapp.model.Person;

public class PersonUnpersonValueFactory implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, CheckBox>, ObservableValue<CheckBox>> {

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<CheckBox> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, CheckBox> param) {
        Person person = param.getValue();
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(person.isUnperson());

        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
            person.setUnperson(new_val);
            System.out.println(new_val);
        });
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(checkBox);
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

private Boolean unperson;

    ...

    //unperson
    public Boolean isUnperson() {
        return this.unperson;
    }

    public void setUnperson(Boolean unperson){
        this.unperson = unperson;
    }

    ...

}
```

**PersonView.fxml**

```
<?import usersapp.controller.PersonUnpersonValueFactory?>

...

<TableView fx:id="personTable" editable="true" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="285.0" prefWidth="378.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="53.0">
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-alignment: CENTER;">
                           <cellValueFactory>
                              <PersonUnpersonValueFactory />
                           </cellValueFactory>
                           <graphic>
                              <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" />
                           </graphic>
                        </TableColumn>
                        ...
                     </columns>
                  </TableView>
```

Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, я нашёл то, что требуется.

[image: пример]

    класс Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tabel Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

класс Controller:

```
package sample;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Names> tabel;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Names, Boolean> col1;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Names, String> col2;

    private static boolean chck;

    @FXML
    void checkBoxInitialize(ActionEvent event) {
        chck = checkBox.isSelected() ? true : false;
        for (Names n : data) {
            n.setCheck(chck);
        }
    }

    ObservableList<Names> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Names, Boolean>("check"));
        col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Names, String>("name"));

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            data.add(new Names("Name " + i));
        }
        tabel.setItems(data);
    }
}
```

класс Names:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;

public class Names {
    private CheckBox check;
    private String name;

    public CheckBox getCheck() {
        return check;
    }

    public void setCheck(Boolean x) {
        if(x) {
            check.setSelected(true);
        } else {
          check.setSelected(false);
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Names(String name) {
        check = new CheckBox();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

файл FXML (sample.fxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <TableView fx:id="tabel" editable="true" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="col1" prefWidth="26.0" resizable="false">
                    <graphic>
                        <CheckBox fx:id="checkBox" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#checkBoxInitialize" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="23.0" />
                    </graphic>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn fx:id="col2" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="572.0" text="Имя" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```